# Get the Store count of each state by Join using Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, stored-procedures, inner-join

I have a query `select * from TBL_RRSOC_STATE_CENTROID;` which gives me the data of each and every state.

So by joining with Master table, I want count of the store on the basis of `STATE`. So I wrote the join query like below

```
select  cen.X, cen.Y, cen.R4GSTATECODE, cen.R4GSTATENAME, rrs.STATE, COUNT(rrs.STORE_CODE)
from TBL_RRSOC_STATE_CENTROID cen
 INNER JOIN TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO RRS ON CEN.R4GSTATENAME = RRS.STATE
order by 1 desc;
```

But I am getting error as

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

I want the count of store in each state. Please suggest how to get this

Comment: You need a group by ... cause you have a count.

Comment: @Plirkee: group by what ?? all columns

Comment: It depends ... but yeh  - could be all ... `group by cen.X, cen.Y, cen.R4GSTATECODE, cen.R4GSTATENAME, rrs.STATE`

Comment: @Plirkee: now it is working, but there are 28 states and I am getting only 22 rows

Comment: you are doing an inner join ... so you see only the sates that have some records...

Comment: Left (or right) outer join is what you probably need...

Comment: @Plirkee: ok let me try and check

Comment: yes, its working..thanks @Plirkee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your final query would look like the following

```
select  cen.X, cen.Y, cen.R4GSTATECODE, cen.R4GSTATENAME, rrs.STATE, 
COUNT(rrs.STORE_CODE)
FROM TBL_RRSOC_STATE_CENTROID cen
LEFT JOIN TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO RRS 
ON CEN.R4GSTATENAME = RRS.STATE
GROUP BY cen.X, cen.Y, cen.R4GSTATECODE, cen.R4GSTATENAME, rrs.STATE
ORDER BY 1 desc;
```